# How to add meta title?

Tags: meta-tags

I want to add this line above my title

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width,  minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

How can I ?

Comment: take a look at this https://drupal.org/project/custom_meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this on html.tpl.php in drupal 7 , else you can have it on page.tpl.php.

As a note if you are putting it on page.tpl.php remember you have to put it on every other page overriding template page--front.tpl.php etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) function. Add something like this to a page preprocess function:

```
$tag = array(
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'name' =>  'viewport',
    'content' => 'initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width,  minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($tag, 'meta_viewport');
```